# Save session state as unique url for sharing with others

Tags: php, mysql, session, hash

I am using sessions to store items in a users wish list.

The wishlist is stored as a simple array of unique item ids -
An average user would store around 40 items in the wish list but it is possible that a user may wish to add as many as a few hundred items in their wish list.

I would like to generate a unique URL so that they can revisit their wishlist later, or share the wishlist with others who could use it as a starting point for their own lists.

I am not collecting any data from the user, and they will not have an account to link their wishlist data with.

The 2 methods of dealing with this that I am considering are:

Storing the data as a hash on the end of the URL, either as a url encoded serialised string or base64 encoded string.
This seems preferable as I will not need to store the wishlists and this offers a large amount of flexibility for users to modify existing lists, however I suspect that this will become unworkable if the number of items in the wishlist increases and the URL length grows beyond workable character counts.

OR

Generate a url with a unique Id and save the wishlist to the database. The problem I see with this is that a new entry will be added to the database every time a user wishes to generate a URL, and since these entries won't be tied to any one user, a new entry will need to be generated every time a user makes any modification to a list.

Is there another better approach to handling this, or a way to manage the problems associated with the above methods?

Comment: I'd prefer the former but I'm currently unsure how best to achieve it.

Comment: I agree that the hash would be a very convenient way of doing this. If you go the database route, you will have to have a way of expiring those database entries after a certain amount of time as well which would be a pain.

Comment: What specifically are you worried about with taking the DB route?

Comment: The problem I see, is that there would not be an obvious time to remove records (other than to expire them after a set period of time) as a generated URL will not be locked down to any particular user. So I am concerned that this could potentially lead to an extremely large number of records over time - I may be unnecessarily concerned for this particular project - but I was curious if there was a more elegant approach that didn't require storing any of the lists.

Comment: These wishlists never need to be edited? If they did, it would be a pain if a user had to email friends the new url everytime they edit the list.

Comment: food for thought - assuming ave of 45 products per list, thats prob about 200 bytes of storage. 5 mil lists would take about 1GB of disk.

Comment: Yes - It sounds like the DB approach is probably going to pan out to be the best - it seems unwieldy but It sounds like i'm more likely to face serious problems with URL lengths than database resources.

Comment: again, it depends on how you store the data. If the "wish list" is just a table with 3 ints, it's most definitely not going to take 3 gigs for 5k records. The data has to be normalized.

Comment: As a quick example, I have a table that has an id (int), a product_id (int), a selection_id (int), a quantity(smallint), a price (int), a created date and updated date with 150,000 records. This table is only 9.5MB (incl indexes). You people are over estimating storage needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think going the database route will be the most flexible solution in the long run. Adding/removing records every time a user makes a selection shouldn't be an issue as long as your data is well modeled. A "selection" should create no more than record referencing two things by key; a user, a product plus a quantity and price perhaps.

That said, I would do it with a model similar to this:

- product (id, ...)
- selection_set (id, name)
- selection (product_id, selection_set_id, quantity, price)
- wishlist (public_hash, selection_set_id)

Wishlist is separate from selection_set because you could reuse selection_set for other things, like a shopping cart or order.

Once that's done, you can just store the public_hash in a cookie/session and give them a url to link to.

Would that work for the scenario you had in mind? or are there any additional constraints?

**Alternate solutions:**

Even though I think the database is a viable solution, I can think of a couple of alternatives:

**Zip and encode data:**

> You can take a comma separated list of wishlist item ids (or some sort of unique identifier), then base64_encode( gzinflate( $list ) ) and use that as your hash. You can then use gzdeflate( base64_decode( $hash ) ) to get your list of items. In order to avoid doing this on every page load, you can continue storing your selection within the session and only re-generate the hash when the list changes.

gzdeflate + base64 should keep your hash within reasoable lengths for up to very large wishlist selections. You can write some unit tests to see how long a hash/list can get hypothetically.

This method feels like a total hack :-)

**Use [Redis](http://redis.io/):**

You can set up a redis server and store wishlists on it. It'll be persistent, scalable, fast and easy to access.

Comment: The concern is that this could potentially generate an unnecessarily large number of records - Ideally I want the URL to be unique to the particular combination of items on the list. There will be thousands of items to choose from, so the possible combinations that could potentially need to be stored in the database could be immense.

Comment: You could make the records expire after a certain period of time. I really don't see how else you could persist their wishlist so that it can be accessed later. I run databases (mysql) that have tables with over 10 million records similar to what you need without issues.

Comment: I just thought of something that is kind of a hack, but it doesn't use the database.. Editing momentarily

Comment: Thanks thatjuan - you've given good input on both methods. It sounds like using the DB is probably the more sensible approach, but the zip and encode method would fit my original requirements well - I'm going to play around with both and consider the pros and cons further.

Comment: Do post back when you test the zip method, if you do. :)